# How to display two local images side by side in jupyter?

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, display

I want to display two images, that I have them **saved locally**, in one single makedown cell **side-by-side**?  I found previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647774/how-to-include-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-markdown-for-ipython-notebook-jupyt?answertab=active#tab-top) but it uses `HTML()` not `Image()` method.

The way I tried was:

```
from IPython.core.display import Image, display
display(Image('/whateverfile/counts1.png',width=100,height=100), Image('/whateverfile/counts2',width=100, height=100))
```

But that did not work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: A possible duplicate: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647774/how-to-include-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-markdown-for-ipython-notebook-jupyt).

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
display(HTML("<table><tr><td><img src='/image/counts1.png'></td><td><img src='/image/counts2'></td></tr></table>"))
```

Set other parameters as you like.

---

Or maybe using nbextensions and splitting the cell in two (having 2 outputs side by side) would fit your needs?

Comment: I could not display them.  I am wondering do the images `counts1.png` and `counts2.png` have to be in a specific file in my computer?

Comment: Try to put them wherever folder you run your notebook in, and use paths like `src='counts1.png'`. Tell me if it works and we will work from there.

Comment: you are amazing it worked, but not sure how! So, do I have to have the images and the jupyter notebook to be in the same folder so the HTML works? Could not I give the complete path of `counts1.png` and `count2.png` wherever they are in?

Comment: Path like `/image/counts1.png` is an absolute path. Are you sure you want to use an absolute path to file, not the relative one (like `./image/counts1.png`)?

Comment: Not sure.  Could you please tell me how that would differ?

Comment: If the image files are located in your home folder, then absolute path is `~/image/counts1.png`. If they are located in the folder inside the same folder as notebook, then relative path is the path relative to the notebook location. E.g. if notebooks are in `~/notebooks/` then file located in `~/notebooks/images/name` would have relative path like `./images/name`. More on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, Thank you so much!