# Is there a pure Markdown way to include two images side by side in Jupyter?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, markdown

There is a useful Python solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647774/how-to-include-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-markdown-for-ipython-notebook-jupyt?answertab=active#tab-top) to put two images side by side in the notebook, but is there a language agnostic way that does the trick using only Jupyter's own markdown? Something like

```
![](path/to/image1) # insert magic here # ![](path/to/image2)
```

that displays the images side by side?

This would be useful in my case cause I would prefer not to break a markdown cell into two and put code in between, but I also would find this helpful in case the notebook is not running Python. I personally run Julia quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be using `img` tags with the same `align` attribute:

```
<img src="path/to/image1" align="left"/><img src="path/to/image2" align="left"/>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to do the trick, my images still appear one below the other.

Comment: @rodrigolece Are you sure that your images are small enough? Try to provide a small `width` such as 100.

Comment: If you want to return to having markdown text after using the align tag without needing to make a new cell you can follow [here](https://owlcation.com/stem/how-to-align-images-side-by-side) and put `<p style="clear: both;">` to clear the aligning to left.  Also with the addition of `style="margin-right: 1%;"` to the `img` tag of the first you can add spacing between the two.