# How do I make 2 images appear side by side in Jupyter notebook (iPython)?

Tags: python, image, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to display 2 PNG images in iPython side by side.

My code to do this is:

```
from IPython.display import Image, HTML, display

img_A = '\path\to\img_A.png'
img_B = '\path\to\img_B.png'

display(HTML("<table><tr><td><img src=img_A></td><td><img src=img_B></td></tr></table>"))
```

But it doesn't output the images, and instead only displays placeholders for the 2 images:

[image]

I tried the following as well:

```
s = """<table>
<tr>
<th><img src="%s"/></th>
<th><img src="%s"/></th>
</tr></table>"""%(img_A, img_B)
t=HTML(s)
display(t)
```

But the result is the same:

[image]

The images are in the path for sure, because I verified by displaying them in a pop up:

```
plt.imshow(img_A)
plt.imshow(img_B)
```

and they do appear in the pop ups.

How do I make the 2 images appear side by side in iPython?

Comment: Not sure but would solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647774/how-to-include-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-markdown-for-ipython-notebook-jupyt be helpful ?

Comment: @student The accepted solution in the link you provided is the exact thing I'm trying, but it doesn't work in code section - maybe it only works in markdown section.

Comment: Did you check your browser console for any errors?

Comment: @akarilimano Yes, no error was reported in the console.

Comment: `<img src=img_A>` will not magically fill in the variable value. You will have to do that.

Comment: @KlausD. Oh! And how do I do that?

Comment: https://pyformat.info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include two pictures side by side in Markdown for IPython Notebook (Jupyter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647774/how-to-include-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-markdown-for-ipython-notebook-jupyt)

Comment: incredible that, after all these years, some "pretty display image" methods have not been implemented.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try using `matplotlib`. You can read image to `numpy` array by using `mpimg.imread` ([*documentation*](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html)) from matplotlib, then you can use `subplots` (*[documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)*) and for creating two columns for figures and finally `imshow` (*[documetation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)*) to display images.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import rcParams

%matplotlib inline

# figure size in inches optional
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 11 ,8

# read images
img_A = mpimg.imread('\path\to\img_A.png')
img_B = mpimg.imread('\path\to\img_B.png')

# display images
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(img_A)
ax[1].imshow(img_B)
```

Comment: But I have a problem I get the image within a cartesian frame. How to solve this?

Comment: You can do this:
# display images
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2);
ax[0].imshow(img_A); ax[0].axis('off');
ax[1].imshow(img_B); ax[1].axis('off')

Comment: in my case this solution does not work as it is: I only get some strangely labeles axes.

Answer (score 17):

`matplotlib` is a very good tool for plotting but I found it very heavy and slow for scenarios where I simply need a fast and easy way to display bigger number of images.
To solve this I'm using [IPyPlot package](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot):

```
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(images_list, max_images=20, img_width=150)
```

You would get a plot similar to this:
[image]

Comment: in my case, empty images are displayed, even if the path is correct and other methods for reading the image run fine.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax `images[labels == 'tents']` and I wasn't able to find information by googling, can you explain how it works ?

Comment: @Damien don't mind that. You can just pass a list of images as a parameter. In case of that syntax I simply filter the list of `labels` by looking for string `tents` which returns a list of True and False values adequately and that's what I use for slicing of selecting specific images from my `images` list

Answer (score 7):

Kind of late but i found out about this over [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html)

You can do it via Hbox.
Hbox is a special container where you can add widgets. It aims at providing an efficient way to lay out, align and distribute space among items in a given space. Although its a bit cumbersome to define so many elements just to display 2 images you can add a lot more functionality like sliders, dropdown menus as well as buttons making your Jupiter notebook more interactive.

```
import IPython.display as display
import ipywidgets as widgets

img1=open('path_to_image','rb').read()
wi1 = widgets.Image(value=img1, format='jpg', width=300, height=400)
img2=open('path_to_image','rb').read()
wi2 = widgets.Image(value=img2, format='jpg', width=300, height=400)
a=[wi1,wi2]
wid=widgets.HBox(a)
display.display(wid)
```

Comment: The above method works best for png images(it essentially converts the image into binary and then displays it as per my knowledge). Found what you need here  --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640375/displaying-gifs-in-jupyter-notebook-using-widgets

Answer (score 2):

This easy solution worked great for me:

```
from IPython.display import Video, Image, HTML, display

image_path1 = "/myfolder/my_img1.jpg"
image_path2 = "/myfolder/my_img2.jpg"


HTML(f"""
    <div class="row">
            <img src={image_path1} style="width:30%"> </img>
            <img src={image_path1} style="width:53.2%"> </img>
    </div>
    """)
```

I put in different widths for if you have a portrait and a landscape picture, but that is up to you depending on the images and the aspect ratios.

Comment: It's easy to adapt your code to image-text pairs.

Answer (score 1):

For some guys who may want to place an image and a text snippet side by side(adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326284/3552975)):

```
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML, display
b64_img =  base64.b64encode(open('./path', 'rb').read()).decode('ascii')
txt = "sjfa;\nakd;f\nsdfa"
display(HTML(f"""
    <div class="row">
    <img style="float:left;margin-right:30px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{b64_img}" width="400" height="300" />
    <div style="font-size:10px;white-space:pre;">{txt}</div>
    </div>
    """))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
from IPython.display import Image, HTML, display

img_A = '\path\to\img_A.png'
img_B = '\path\to\img_B.png'

display(HTML("<table><tr><td><img src={0}></td><td><img src={1}></td></tr></table>".format(image_A,img_B)))
```

You mistook the variable name as variable itself.