# How to display the images side by side in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have used the following code but it is displaying the images vertically. I want them to display side by side in a Jupyter Notebook.

```
display(Image.open(BytesIO(Item[iii][b'imgs'])))
display(Image.open(BytesIO(Item[jjj][b'imgs'])))
```

---

I have tried using this code

```
display(HTML("<table><tr><td>display(Image.open(BytesIO(Item[jjj][b'imgs']))))
```

but it is display the text `display(Image.open(BytesIO(Item[jjj][b'imgs']))))`

Comment: Did you try also with html layout? display method also support html.

Comment: Create a new image which has both images inside of it side by side.

Comment: Yeah I have tried using this code 
display(HTML("<table><tr><td>display(Image.open(BytesIO(Item[jjj][b'imgs'])))) but it is display the text . "display(Image.open(BytesIO(Item[jjj][b'imgs'])))) "

Answer (score 12):

Using layout features of ipywidgets you can do that

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import IPython.display as display
## Read images from file (because this is binary, maybe you can find how to use ByteIO) but this is more easy
img1 = open('image1.jpeg', 'rb').read()
img2 = open('image2.jpeg', 'rb').read()
## Create image widgets. You can use layout of ipywidgets only with widgets.
## Set image variable, image format and dimension.
wi1 = widgets.Image(value=img1, format='png', width=300, height=400)
wi2 = widgets.Image(value=img2, format='png', width=300, height=400)
## Side by side thanks to HBox widgets
sidebyside = widgets.HBox([wi1, wi2])
## Finally, show.
display.display(sidebyside)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . However I am unable to modify the height and width of the images. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: No problem, that is aesthetic not requiered. I want equal size widget images.

Comment: Interesting alternative to `pyplot`. See also this [custom package  IPyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61592610/774575).

Answer (score 2):

Displaying two images side by side

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img1 = plt.imread('<PATH_TO_IMG1>')
img2 = plt.imread('<PATH_TO_IMG2>')

NUM_ROWS = 1
IMGs_IN_ROW = 2
f, ax = plt.subplots(NUM_ROWS, IMGs_IN_ROW, figsize=(16,6))

ax[0].imshow(img1)
ax[1].imshow(img2)

ax[0].set_title('image 1')
ax[1].set_title('image 2')

title = 'side by side view of images'
f.suptitle(title, fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hiding ticks and labels would be better for images, and ensuring the pixel ratio is not altered would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can slightly modify the code above to display a grid of images.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img1 = plt.imread('<PATH_TO_IMG1>')
img2 = plt.imread('<PATH_TO_IMG2>')
images = [img1, img2]*3

NUM_ROWS = 2
IMGs_IN_ROW = 3

f, ax_arr = plt.subplots(NUM_ROWS, IMGs_IN_ROW, figsize=(16,8))

for j, row in enumerate(ax_arr):
    for i, ax in enumerate(row):
        ax.imshow(images[j*IMGs_IN_ROW+i])
        ax.set_title(f'image {j*IMGs_IN_ROW+i+1}')

title = 'displaying images matrix'
f.suptitle(title, fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The initial answer is already a grid of subplots, but it has only one row. If you populate a 2D grid you don't know if you have enough images to fill all the grid cells. What you need to do to hide the empty cells would be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subplot.

```
import pylab 
pylab.subplot(1, 2, 1)
pylab.plot(range(10))
pylab.subplot(1, 2, 2)
pylab.plot(range(20))
```