# Displaying gifs in jupyter notebook using widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How do you use python widgets to display gifs in a jupyeter notebook.

I have tried:

```
gif_box = widgets.Image("sample.gif")
```

or

```
gif_box = widgets.Video("sample.gif")
```

but receiver error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Regardless of what I try it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read your image into a file handler and read it into a byte string before you can pass it into the widget like so:

```py
# read file as bytes and get file handler. use `with` to ensure 
# your file is closed after you're done reading it
with open("sample.gif", "rb") as file:
    # read file as string into `image` 
    image = file.read()

widgets.Image(
    value=image,
    format='gif'
)
```

See the [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Image) for the `Image` widget.