# Is it impossible to put two images side by side in Jupyter notebook markdown using HTML?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook, and I would like to show an image side-by-side using `Markdown` block. For an image,

```
<img src="image1.png" width="400">
```

shows me an image, but I'm wondering if there is any way to put pictures side-by-side using `Markdown` block.

---

#### Try

I've tried the following :

```
<style type="imgContainer">
    float:left;
</style>

<div class="image12">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="../EyeTracking_data/Figures/Freq.png" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">    
        <img src="../EyeTracking_data/Figures/Freq.png" width="200"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

but this only shows the plots with one on top and the other on the bottom.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
display(HTML("<table><tr><td><img src='img1'></td><td><img src='img2'></td></tr></table>"))
```

[How to include two pictures side by side in Markdown for IPython Notebook (Jupyter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647774/how-to-include-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-markdown-for-ipython-notebook-jupyt)